# Flutter in app subscription returns "Pending transaction"

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I'm using this Package [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) in my flutter project.
I had managed to run few successful tests. But recently I bumped into this exception

*Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(storekit_duplicate_product_object, There is a pending transaction for the same product identifier. Please either wait for it to be finished or finish it manually using `completePurchase` to avoid edge cases., {applicationUsername: null, requestData: null, quantity: 1, productIdentifier: PB_12, simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox: true}, null)*

My approach is as follows

1. Connect platform specific IAP and select the subscription item.
2. Pass that subscription purchase result(the receipt) to my backend to verify/update the user purchase.
3. Navigate the user to premium options.

In the latter part I will give what code I use so far, this code context was altered from the In_app_purchase public page example.

when I try to debug, I saw that purchaseDatails keeps a list of purchases and that passes In the *_listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList)* method. I'm implementing a POST method *updateUserSubscription(purchaseDetails)* to pass the receipt for the subscription but since that parameter comes as a list the function executes more than one times.

Following my code would you guide me where to change and what should I do to achieve the above three steps. A code explanation will be more than helpful.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
    DateTime noADDate;
    var fiftyDaysFromNow = currentDate.add(new Duration(days: 50));
    print(
        '${fiftyDaysFromNow.month} - ${fiftyDaysFromNow
            .day} - ${fiftyDaysFromNow.year} ${fiftyDaysFromNow
            .hour}:${fiftyDaysFromNow.minute}');
    //
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdates =
        InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdates.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      // handle error here.
    });
    initStoreInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

Future<void> initStoreInfo() async {
    final bool isAvailable = await _connection.isAvailable();
    if (!isAvailable) {
      setState(() {
        _isAvailable = isAvailable;
        _products = [];
        _purchases = [];
        _notFoundIds = [];
        _consumables = [];
        _purchasePending = false;
        _loading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse =
    // await _connection.queryProductDetails(_kProductIds.toSet());
    await _connection.queryProductDetails(Platform.isIOS
        ? _kiOSProductIds.toSet()
        : _kAndroidProductIds.toSet()); //_kProductIds.toSet());
    if (productDetailResponse.error != null) {
      setState(() {
        _queryProductError = productDetailResponse.error.message;
        _isAvailable = isAvailable;
        _products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
        _purchases = [];
        _notFoundIds = productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs;
        _consumables = [];
        _purchasePending = false;
        _loading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    if (productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _queryProductError = null;
        _isAvailable = isAvailable;
        _products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
        _purchases = [];
        _notFoundIds = productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs;
        _consumables = [];
        _purchasePending = false;
        _loading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse purchaseResponse =
    await _connection.queryPastPurchases();
    if (purchaseResponse.error != null) {
      // handle query past purchase error..
    }
    final List<PurchaseDetails> verifiedPurchases = [];
    for (PurchaseDetails purchase in purchaseResponse.pastPurchases) {
      if (await _verifyPurchase(purchase)) {
        verifiedPurchases.add(purchase);
      }
    }
    List<String> consumables = await ConsumableStore.load();
    setState(() {
      _isAvailable = isAvailable;
      _products = productDetailResponse.productDetails;
      _purchases = verifiedPurchases;
      _notFoundIds = productDetailResponse.notFoundIDs;
      _consumables = consumables;
      _purchasePending = false;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> stack = [];
    if (_queryProductError == null) {
      stack.add(
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              _buildConnectionCheckTile(),
              // mainBody,
              _buildProductList(),

              FlatButton(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),

                height: 50.0,

                color: selectedProductDetail == null
                    ? Color(0xFF03B898).withOpacity(0.5)
                    : Color(0xFF03B898),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  side: BorderSide(
                    width: 0.0,
                    color: selectedProductDetail == null
                        ? Color(0xFF03B898).withOpacity(0.5)
                        : Color(0xFF03B898),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  // dialogConfirm();
                  if (selectedProductDetail == null) {
                    return;
                  }

                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Dialog(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                          ),
                          elevation: 0.0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          child: ModelPayment(selectedProductDetail.price,
                              // selectedProductDetail.skuDetail.subscriptionPeriod,
                              buttonClick: () {
                                PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
                                  productDetails: selectedProductDetail,
                                  applicationUserName: null,
                                  sandboxTesting: true,
                                );
                                if (selectedProductDetail.id ==
                                    _kConsumableId) {
                                  _connection.buyConsumable(
                                      purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
                                      autoConsume: _kAutoConsume ||
                                          Platform.isIOS);
                                } else {
                                  _connection.buyNonConsumable(
                                      purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
                                }
                              }),
                        );
                      });
                },
                child: new Text(
                  'SUBSCRIBE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'poppins',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
//                        ),
//                       padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              )

              // _buildConsumableBox(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      stack.add(Center(
        child: Text(_queryProductError),
      ));
    }
    if (_purchasePending) {
      stack.add(
        Stack(
          children: [
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.3,
              child: const ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
//ModelPayment is a Dialog box with Purchase details and a call back to the button in it.

Future<void> consume(String id) async {
    await ConsumableStore.consume(id);
    final List<String> consumables = await ConsumableStore.load();
    setState(() {
      _consumables = consumables;
    });
  }

  void showPendingUI() {
    setState(() {
      _purchasePending = true;
    });
  }

  Future<void> deliverProduct(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    print('deliver product');
    // IMPORTANT!! Always verify a purchase purchase details before delivering the product.
    if (purchaseDetails.productID == _kConsumableId) {
      await ConsumableStore.save(purchaseDetails.purchaseID);
      List<String> consumables = await ConsumableStore.load();
      setState(() {
        _purchasePending = false;
        _consumables = consumables;
      });
      print('reached here');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _purchases.add(purchaseDetails);
        _purchasePending = false;
      });
      print('jumped here');
    }
    // updateUserSubscription(purchaseDetails);
  }

Future<bool> _verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) {
    // IMPORTANT!! Always verify a purchase before delivering the product.
    // For the purpose of an example, we directly return true.
    // return Future<bool>.value(true);
    return Future<bool>.value(true);
  }

  void _handleInvalidPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) {
    // handle invalid purchase here if  _verifyPurchase` failed.

    print('invalid purchase');
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        showPendingUI();
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          handleError(purchaseDetails.error);
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
          bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          if (valid) {
            await deliverProduct(purchaseDetails).whenComplete(() {
              print(purchaseDetails.productID.toString());
              updateUserSubscription(purchaseDetails);
            });
                // updateUserSubscription(purchaseDetails);
                } else {
                _handleInvalidPurchase(purchaseDetails);
                return;
                }
            }
                //
                if (Platform.isAndroid)
            {
              if (!_kAutoConsume &&
                  purchaseDetails.productID == _kConsumableId) {
                await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance
                    .consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);
              }
            }
            if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
              await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance
                  .completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
            }
          }
        });
  }
```

I really don't need to fetch the whole list to pass to the method updateUserSubscription(). Just need to pass the most recently selected subscription purchase to that particular user.

Comment: To the package, it looks like your trying to buy the same product again, this product is null, it already has a null product in process. Try passing a new product with a radom id or random data. And check before you attempt the transaction, if the product being processed already exists or not. It it exists catch the error and say the error so the app doesn't throw uncaught. Update after this please

Comment: Thank you for the inout @HuthaifaMuayyad. 
Can you provide me a simple code explanation where should I change the approach ? please :)

Comment: Where is the code for `handleError`?